# Overwriting when appending to list of lists in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to group the index of continuous events from a list of events based on their value.

However, there is an error in my code in appending to the events_list list that I can't spot. 
When my code appends it overwrites the values of the previously appended items.

The last print statement returns [[24],[24],[24],[24],[24]] instead of the expected [[0,1,2,3,4],[7],[8,9],[10,11,12],[16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21],[24]]

```
single_events = [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,-1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,1]

events_list = []
current_event = []


for i, event in enumerate(single_events):
    print('\nRecord: ', i, ',\tEvent Type: ', event)
    if (current_event == []) and (event != 0):
        current_event.append(i)
        print('Current Event: ', current_event)

    elif (current_event == []) and (acc == 0):
        pass    

    elif (current_event != []) and (event == single_events[current_event[-1]]):
        current_event.append(i)
        print('Current Event: ', current_event)

    elif (current_event != []) and (event != single_events[current_event[-1]]):
        print('Event to be appended: ', current_event)
        events_list.append(current_event)
        print('\nNEW EVENT LIST!!!: ', events_list)
        current_event[:] = []
        if event == 0:
            pass
        else:
            current_event.append(i)
        print('Current Event: ', current_event)         


print('\n', events_list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reusing the same reference for `current_event` for every iteration.

That:

```
current_event[:] = []
```

empties the list, but keeps the same reference. You need to create a new reference to avoid modifying the previously stored lists, like this:

```
current_event = []
```

by changing just that I get: `[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [7], [8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21]]` as a result

Aside: conditions like `elif (current_event == []) and (acc == 0):` can be better rewritten like:

```
elif not current_event and acc==0:
```

empty list is considered as "Falsy", no need to compare to empty (same thing for `acc` but comparing to 0 is clearer).